# Examples of very easy approximation algorithms

Tags: exercises

I teach 'operations research' at a university where students have moderate skills in very theoretical topics. I'd like to create some problems related to approximation algorithms, with the final question requiring proof regarding performance guarantees. My students might not be able to tackle anything more difficult than, for instance, proving that the NextFit algorithm for the bin-packing problem is 2*OPT by grouping consecutive boxes. Are you aware of other problems and algorithms where performance guarantees could be proven in such an easy way?